# Is there any way to parse html created with javascript in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, flutter-http

I would like to use [metadata_fetch package](https://pub.dev/packages/metadata_fetch) to get the OGP.
The implementation of this package uses the [html (parse) package](https://pub.dev/packages/html). And it worked for most of the web pages.
However, there are some web pages, like [this one](https://video.unext.jp/title/SID0050925), that cannot be fetched. I think this was because the html was generated by javascript. Is there any way to parse such a page as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a `webview_flutter` and inject some sort of Javascript that would walk the DOM for you and serialize it for return, which of course would happen after the page javascript has already built up the DOM.  I haven't done that, but it might be a fun project.

EDIT:  it might be as simple as capturing the string response of `document.firstElementChild.outerHTML`.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in my reply. I'll try it. Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others, here's a source I made based on an idea from [@Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz).

```dart
const String url_unext = 'https://video.unext.jp/title/SID0050925';
WebViewController _controller;
Stack(
  children: [
    WebView(
      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
        _controller = controller;
      },
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      initialUrl: url_unext,
      onPageFinished: (_) async {
        html = await _controller.evaluateJavascript("window.document.firstElementChild.outerHTML;");
        // Use Metadata_fetch to parse
        final data = getOpenGraphDataFromResponse(html);
        print(data);
      },
    ),
    // else widget here
    Container(),
  ],
),
```

However, I am concerned about running a malicious script. If there is a better way, please let me know. I'm looking into the possibility of using [oembed](https://oembed.com/).
Once again, thank you very much, [@Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz).

Comment: I suspect the webview will be contained within a sandbox.  There's no way to refer to any outside data or channels from the page.

Comment: I see! I'm sorry for being a noob. I can’t tell you how much I appreciate.